# How can I refer to @dynamic properties in (NSString *)description

Tags: objective-c, dynamic

I'm trying to override -(NSString *)description in a class defined with ONLY @dynamic properties.

So my class looks like this... (excerpt)...

```
@implementation SomeClass
  @dynamic somePropertyOne;
  @dynamic somePropertyTwo;
  @dynamic somePropertyThree;

-(NSString *)description
{
  return (NSString stringWithFormat:@"somePropertyOne = %@",somePropertyOne)
}

@end
```

and I'm getting an error message saying "Can't resolve variable 'somePropertyOne'" in my description override.  Is it not possible to refer to a @dynamic property like this?  How can I override description to show this information?

Comment: Does this happen to be a Core Data managed object subclass? In that case you are discouraged from overriding `description` (see https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdManagedObjects.html).

Comment: Yes it does happpen to be a Core Data subclass.  Thanks for the link.  I'll remove my override after I finish debugging.  Trying to find a bug unrelated to Core Data and just needed to know what this class had for values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `self.somePropertyOne`.

A `dynamic` property is just like a normal property in terms of definition. The difference is that `@synthesize` (which is the actual counterpart, not the property definition) creates the accessor methods in the current class whereas `@dynamic` indicates that a superclass implements the accessor methods.

Comment: `@dynamic` doesn't really mean that a superclass implements them,  it just indicates that the accessor methods' messages will be responded to at runtime one way or another. In other words, it tells the compiler, "don't worry, I know I didn't write regular accessor methods for this property, but they'll be available at runtime".